# How to make a matrix positive semidefinite?

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

Given the following matrix, where $a$ and $b$ are real,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
b & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
how do I find the values for $a$ and $b$ (or their relationship) which makes the matrix positive semidefinite?

So $x^TAx\ge0$, which would give me $a{x_1}^2+2bx_1x_2+{x_2}^2\ge0$. How do I proceed from here? Should I attempt to diagonalize this? I don't think I can solve for the eigenvalues with $a$ and $b$ around.

Should I make the determinant equals zero? Something like $b^2-a=0$, so the answer would be $a=b^2$? Would that make sense? Or is there something else I should do first?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See whether this helps you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332456/how-to-make-a-matrix-positive-semidefinite

Comment: Positive semidefinite matrix has nonegative eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues aren't so difficult to find, since we are only interested in their sign. Let's try:
$$(a-\lambda)(1-\lambda)-b^2=\lambda^2-(a+1)\lambda+a-b^2$$

The product of the roots of this polynomial is $a-b^2$, which is non negative for $a\ge b^2$.

The sum of the roots is $a+1$, and this must be non negative, that is, $a\ge -1$, which is redundant, since $b^2\ge 0$.

The condition is $a\ge b^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
b & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then eigenvalues of A are given by 
$$\begin{align}
\det(A-\lambda I)&=(a-\lambda)(1-\lambda)-b^2\\
&=\lambda^2-(a+1)\lambda+(a-b^2)
\end{align}$$

Now find $a$ and $b$ ranges such that the roots of the above quadratic (eigenvalues) are non-negative.